# When does squaring the square root of a function give me the absolute value of the function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Why does $[\sqrt{f(x)}]^2=f(x) $ , but $\sqrt{g^2(x)}=|g(x)|$ ?

Comment: The first statement is only true if $f(x) \ge 0$ (consider $f(x) = \sin(x)$ as a counterexample). The second is because we have to account for the case where $g(x)$ may be negative, but $\sqrt{x}$ only outputs nonnegative numbers.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer But isn't f(x) anyway going to be always $>=$ 0 if we are talking about real values, hence the range of  of sin(x) will be [0,1] ?

Comment: Why would $f(x)$ always be nonnegative?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer wouldn't that give complex solutions in some cases ?

Comment: That's precisely the point and is why the two are not necessarily the same thing. If $f(x) \ge 0$, then yes, 

$$\left( \sqrt{f(x)} \right)^2 = f(x) = | f(x) | = \sqrt{ f(x)^2 }$$

Try playing with some examples in Desmos and noticing that the graphs you get won't always be the same if $f(x)$ can be sometimes negative.